# return all images in array from latest added

Tags: php, arrays, image, sorting

I want to make an array that return every images from a folder from the latest added to the first one.

So, create an array it's ok, get the time of each image added it's ok, 
sort images from latest to first it's ok.

For the moment I only can get the latest image added, but I don't know how can I create a while that will show all my images?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$tabFich = array();
$allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator("../img/peinture/");

foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if (!$fileinfo->isFile() || !in_array($fileinfo->getExtension(), $allowedExtensions))
            continue;
        $tabFich[$fileinfo->getCTime()] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
}

ksort($tabFich);
$lastFile = end($tabFich);
?>

<div class="vs-peint" style="background:url(../img/peinture/<?php echo $lastFile; ?>)"></div>
```

Comment: Your `$tabFich` array is storing all the images from the directory. What exactly you are looking here?

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar i want to show all images of the directory in order from latest to the first one added

Comment: Like image names? Or as in the div background like you've shown above for one div?

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar yes as a background of div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this and let me know if it works for you

```
$tabFich = array();
$allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator("../img/peinture/");

foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {

        if (!$fileinfo->isFile() || !in_array($fileinfo->getExtension(), $allowedExtensions))
            continue;

        array_push($tabFich, array("file_datetime" => $fileinfo->getCTime(), "file_name" => $fileinfo->getFilename()));
    }
}

usort($tabFich, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['file_datetime'] - $b['file_datetime'];
});

foreach ($tabFich as $key => $value) {?>

    <div class="vs-peint" style="background:url('../img/peinture/<?php echo $value['file_name']; ?>'); height: 400px; width: 400px;"></div>

<?php }
```

Comment: Edited my answer; Added height and width to div so that image will be visible.

Comment: You're welcome :) can you please up-vote and accept my answer ;)